Characterization of the rank of a Lie algebra
I'm reading "Affine Lie algebras and Quantum Groups" written by Fuchs, and now struggling with the definition of the rank of a Lie algebra. In p.14, it says that

Introducing a formal variable $t$ ,the polynomial in $t$ defined as
$\det(t-R_{\mathrm{ad}}(x))=\sum_{n=0}^{d}p_n(x)t^n$ determines certain polynomial functions $p_n$ in $\mathcal{G}$; the smallest integer $n$ for which $p_n(x)\not\equiv0$ is called the rank of the Lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$.

On the other hand, according to Humphreys the definition of the rank of a Lie algebra is the dimension of its CSA. I tried to connect two definitions and thought of the correspondence between $p_n$'s and a basis of some concrete CSA of $\mathcal{G}$.
I'd be appreciate if anyone give me some hints. Thanks!

Hint: $n$ is the smallest (algebraic) multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ for $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ among all $x$. For such an $x$ the corresponding generalised eigenspace for $0$ is a CSA. Not sure how easy this is to show in general though. In a semisimple Lie algebra $x$ will be semisimple and this will be the geometric multiplicity and thus we are just talking about the centraliser of $x$. That the CSA in a semisimple Lie algebra is a centraliser of a single element is definitely somewhere in Humphreys.
